# bound quiver of section -- the dga version?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, quivers

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and  $\mathcal{L} = \{L_0, \cdots, L_n\}$ be a list of distinct line bundles. The (complete) bound quiver of sections associated with $\mathcal{L}$ is a quiver with relation $(Q, R)$ corresponding to the endomorphism algebra $A=\hom_{O_X}(L,L)$ where $L=\oplus_{i=0}^n L_i$, and the hom is the usual hom. This is the version I learned from the lecture note [Explicit Methods in Derived Category of Sheaves](https://www.math.utah.edu/dc/tilting.pdf).

My question is then, suppose one considers the hom-complex $\Lambda = \hom^\bullet(L, L)$ in the dg category of coherent sheaves on $X$, thus $\Lambda$ is a dga and $H^0(\Lambda)=A$,   is there a corresponding quiver description for $\Lambda$?